# "const method" compile error for reading member variable

Tags: c++, constants, stdvector

I would like to know why I get the compile error for the first "const method", while the second one is OK.

```
typedef struct xyz{
    uint16_t xyz1[16];
}XYZ;

class A {
public :
    A() :m_a1(4) { m_a2 = new XYZ[4]; }
    void getSomething() const
    {
        uint16_t* p = m_a1[0].xyz1; //error: invalid conversion from 
                                    //'const uint16_t* {aka const short unsigned int*}' 
                                    //to 'uint16_t* {aka short unsigned int*}'
    }
    voi getSomething2() const
    {
        uint16_t* p = m_a2[0].xyz1; //compile OK
    }
private:
    vector<XYZ> m_a1;
    XYZ*        m_a2;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In a `const` member function, all non-static data members are considered as `const` too, then `m_a1` becomes `const vector<XYZ>`. There's a `const` overload for `std::vector::operator[]`, so perform `operator[]` on a const `std::vector<XYZ>` you'll get a const `XYZ`; whose member `xyz1` becomes `const` too; i.e. `const uint16_t [16]`, which will decay to `const uint16_t*` and can't be converted to `uint16_t*` implicitly.

On the other hand, for the data member `m_a2` with type `XYZ*` in the const member function, will become `XYZ* const` (note it's not `const XYZ*`). i.e. the pointer itself is `const`, but not the pointee. Then with `operator[]`, it'll still return a `XYZ`, not a const `XYZ`. That's why it works well for the following statement.

Comment: Thank you! It is an easily understood answer !

Answer (score 1):

If the member function is `const` all member non `mutable` variables accessed within that method are also treated as const, so the compiler will not allow you to make a non-pointer-to-const point to const member data.  Change your code to this

```
void getSomething() const
{
    const uint16_t* p = m_a1[0].xyz1; 
    // or simply
    // auto* p = m_a1[0].xyz1
}
```

In the second one, the pointer itself is const, but not the data it is pointing to.  So instead of `m_a2` being a `const XYZ*` (which is a pointer to const) like you think, its `XYZ* const` which is a const pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first methodn, the vector object is const, so only const methods of it are used, so the [] operator returns a const reference, and the member `xyz1` is const too.

In the second method, the pointer `m_a2` is const, but **not** the memory location it points to. That's why you don't need the const in the second case.